# Are there any computer systems that can suggest the next word in a sentence based on grammatical correctness?

Tags: parsing

I know Apple and Google have predictive text, but I believe it is purely statistically generated, without analysis of a sentence's grammar. I know various computer parsing systems of human language exist (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Human_languages).

Is there any system which uses the actual grammar rules of a language (for example, the Cambridge Grammar of English) and the actual lexical information of the words (for example, "the" must take a noun as its complement), and a dictionary, to suggest, in an incomplete sentence, which words could come next which would be grammatically correct?

Comment: This was the norm before statistical models. Note that suggesting based merely on grammar would produce infinite options.

Comment: Few languages have an infinite vocabulary from which to choose the next word.

Comment: What do you mean by "actual"? Grammatical rules as stated by Cambridge or anyone are a mere human attempt at capturing the workings of a living language, an these attempts are very useful but neither complete nor perfectly accurate. They do their best to describe how speakers of a language use it and when they perceive it to be used effectively.